# What do you say to a guest when they are departing your country and you are accompanying them e.g. to the airport?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice, sentence-usage

What do the native say to a guest from abroad when:

> **1.** he is in the country and they are departing your country and for instance you are accompanying them to the airport in the car

**OR**

> **2.** when he has left the country (e.g. in an e-mail)
>
> ---
>
> **a)** I hope you have been pleased with your residence in Argentina.
>
> **b)** I hope you have been pleased with your staying in Argentina.
>
> **c)** I hope you have been pleased with your dwelling in Argentina.

I would be grateful if you could suggest me some other better alternatives.

Comment: I’d recommend “(your) stay” as the noun. How I’d say would probably be something like “I hope you enjoyed your stay here!”

Comment: Thank you very much @TylerJamesYoung, but could you please tell me if it is possible to be used in both scenarios above?
Is it polite as much as to be said to a managing director of a well-known company who is much more older than you for instance? :)

Comment: "I hope you [enjoyed your stay](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=%22I+hope+you+enjoyed+your+stay%22)," is perfectly polite for anyone. You can use it in either case (whether the person's stay is ending right now or ended a few days ago).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For 1) only:

> I hope you have enjoyed your stay.

or

> I hope you have enjoyed your visit.

or

> I hope you have enjoyed your trip.

For 1) or 2) :

> I hope you enjoyed your stay/your visit/ your trip.

In the first case, with the visitor about to leave, you can use either enjoyed or have enjoyed because while the visit is mostly in the past, it is technically still ongoing: they haven’t boarded the plane and flown home yet. In the second case, the e-mail is being sent after the trip is clearly and completely over, so you would use the simple past.

“Been pleased with” is perfectly grammatical and understandable, but enjoyed is more idiomatic.